# Insert Result of Select into Variable with Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data

```
Approval_ID
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Query

```
DECLARE 
    @id varchar(8000)

SELECT  @id = COALESCE(@id + ', ', '') + '[' +  Approval_ID  + ']'
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT Approval_ID
   FROM Gate_III_CS_Approval
) Y
```

Result always

> 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I've tried to add Order By

```
ORDER BY len(Approval_ID), Approval_ID
```

but have error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

and I want to the result like this

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Whats should I do?

Update :

```
   ;with cte as (
        SELECT DISTINCT Approval_ID
        FROM Gate_III_CS_Approval
    )

    SELECT @id = STUFF(
                    (SELECT concat(',', '[' + Approval_ID + ']') 
                        FROM cte ORDER BY len(Approval_ID), Approval_id
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: So you're using a `varchar` field for your `Approval_ID`? Instead of an `int` as would be normal?

Comment: Surely the result is going to be `[1],[10],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]`? Because your query is adding square brackets?

Comment: You need to convert to an `int` to sort it the way you want to sort it. Even better would be to use an `int` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CTE` and `STUFF for XML PATH`

`-- replace CTE with your table, this is only an example`

```
declare @id varchar(8000) 

;with cte as (
 select 1 n 
 union all
 select n+1 n from
   cte 
   where n < 10
)
select @id = 
   STUFF((
            SELECT concat(',', n)
            FROM cte
            order by n
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')



select @id
```

`programmatically cast n from alphanumeric to int for sorting`

Comment: @Noob . . . I'm rather surprised that you think that this works for your data.  Your `id` is clearly a string (otherwise you would get a type conversion error).  This is sorting by the value, so the result should still be sorted as a string and not as an integer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yaa I just modified from your script.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to convert `varchar` to `int` for this purpose. I built an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4166/6)

```
DECLARE 
        @id varchar(8000)
    SELECT  @id = COALESCE(@id + ', ', '') + '[' +  CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10))  + ']'
    FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT CAST(id AS INT) ID
       FROM TABLA   
    ) Y

    SELECT  @ID
```

Comment: @Noob this is how you should present your SQL questions in future, with all the data setup and the query ready to run. Makes it so much easier for people to assist you - because the first thing they generally have to do is set all that up themselves.

Comment: Ohh thanks for your advice @DaleBurrell I try to fix it now

Comment: @DaleBurell noted, sorry for this 

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a varchar field instead of an integer for Approval_ID.

For ordering it based on the varchar field, you can try the method from maSTAShuFu's answer.

Here I am updating it with your query from question.

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT CONCAT(',[', Approval_ID,']')
     FROM <your_table>
     ORDER BY cast(Approval_ID as int)
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```